# Heat loss from the greenhouse to the soil

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I need  to find heat loss from the greenhouse. I know how to find heat loss through the walls and roof , but what about soil ? how to find amount heat conductivity loss to the soil ? I would be gratefull for the any reference/method/ article or etc.

Comment: If you can do conductivity for walls etc then ground is just different materials...

Comment: @SolarMike the thing is, in case of walls I know the external temperature (dT). But for the soil I dont.

Comment: So it depends on country / climate, where I am the average ground temperature varies between 5 to 10 degrees annually - research for your country / location...

Comment: I'd be astonished if there weren't tables of soil thermal conductivity for different soil types, water content, etc.  on the interwebz

Comment: @OlegKhegay You cannot just stick a thermometer in the ground?

Comment: @SolarMike it's not the same problem as thermal conduction through walls. The soil is storing the heat, not only transmitting it. It's also changing temperature as it does so, which changes the heat flow rate.

Comment: @user1318499 why don’t you go and have a look at “puit canadenne” ie using a pipe underground as part of ventilation - how much heat do you need to add to change a 3 metre depth of soil one degree....

Comment: @user1318499 the house I built has 20cm of insulation under it - first time the builder had ever used so much - 5cm max...

Comment: @SolarMike You can't simply use the same heat conduction formula that works for glass windows because that requires a temperature difference and a thickness. How can you choose values for those? You might be able to make a lumped conduction model to approximate the continuous soil, but you still need to characterize the model somehow which requires more than just an average soil temperature. Perhaps if you know the skin depth, you can estimate a thickness and treat the temperature as constant, but how do you find the skin depth?

Comment: @user1318499 so for a temperature difference, don't you think there will be a difference between the inside of the greenhouse and the ground temperature 2 metres under the surface? oh, the thickness is the floor level to the depth i.e. 2 meters or 3...

Comment: If you think that's valid, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easy answer:** Net heat loss averaged over day/night is zero because the heat that's transmitted into the soil when the greenhouse is hot is stored in the soil and returned to the greenhouse when the greenhouse becomes colder than the soil.

**Hard answer suggestion:** This problem is called "One-dimensional transient heat conduction in semi-infinite body". Semi-infinite because the ground is infinitely deep in the downwards direction but not in the upwards direction. It's time dependent. The rate of heat loss will go down as it progresses because the ground becomes hotter. You can write and solve the DEs by hand if you wanted a hard exercise in calculus. Here's somebody's working:
https://www.thermalfluidscentral.org/encyclopedia/index.php/One-dimensional_transient_heat_conduction_in_semi-infinite_body

Whiteboard lecture video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8ofOO-iHhk

**Practical answer:** I would use Finite Element Analysis (FEA) which does all that math for you. Download some FEA software and use time dependent or transient heat transfer analysis. This will also allow you to model 2D and 3D effects like heat flow around the edges. The two 1D suggestions above are not strictly correct because of lateral heat flow under the ground but the bigger the greenhouse, the more accurate the 1D approximation is.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Could you say, if Solidworks can help me for solving such kind of problems in the better way than Ansys ? or solidworks is served for different tasks ?

Comment: Yes, SolidWorks Simulation can do that just as well as Ansys for a simple task like this. I think SolidWorks Simulation is a little easier if you're not familiar with either.